# Returning a specific action result from a request filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I have a Filter Attribute registred globally in my MVC app that checks for a specific configuration based on a url. I plan to use a catchall in IIS so for domains that don't match, I want to display a 404 page without redirecting first.

So far I have:

```
public class GetWebsiteConfiguration : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string siteNoteFoundName = "SiteNotFound";
        string controllerName = "Error";
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != siteNoteFoundName && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != controllerName)
        {
            //Code removed for brevity
            IWebsiteService websiteSvc = new WebsiteService();
            Website website = websiteSvc.GetByDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
            if (website != null)
            {
                //load up the website's config - e.g. asset code etc.
            }
            else
            {
                //this is where I'm stuck - I want to return my action result SiteNotFound in my                  
                //controller Error as the filterContext.Result.
                //filterContext.Result = ??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out what to set filterContext.Result to. I tried controller.Execute() but that rendered the original page being requested, as well as the not found page. I know I can do a redirectResult, but I'd rather not...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a base controller and move the SiteNotFound action in there.

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    protected HttpNotFoundResult SiteNotFound(string statusDescription = null)
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult(statusDescription);
        }
}
```

Then you can simply assign the result as:

```
filterContext.Result = filterContext.Controller.SiteNotFound(<description>);
```

You also may want to set this (to avoid IIS into catching those errors)

```
controllerContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - so there is no way to do it unless the actionresult I want to use is within the current filterContext.Controller?

Comment: This is one way that is simple and has minimal friction. Alternatively you can directly create the `HttpNotFoundResult` inside the filter and assign it, unless you have some other custom logic in your controller that you can't/don't want to bring into the filter. Finally, you can always emulate what MVC framework does and instantiate the controller yourself, but then I'd say that maybe filter based approach needs to be revisited. Filters are supposed to be small, simple and self contained. Any code that extends beyond few lines is a code smell that you may be doing too much in one place!